# Trouble removing anaconda3 folder from computer because fail to run pre_uninstall, rmpath, rmreg scripts

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I'm new to using Anaconda/Jupyter Notebook. I was trying to uninstall Anaconda and while I was successful in removing the app, I can't remove the folder "anaconda3" from my files. When I ran the uninstaller inside the folder, I am unable to complete the uninstallation because it failed to run the scripts pre_uninstall, rmpath, rmreg.

How can I fix this? And is it safe to just delete the whole file?

[Picture of uninstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qa0P.png)

I don't even know where to start for this problem... I just want to see the folder gone so I can download an uncorrupted version of Anaconda again.